# How to Tamper HTTP requests which are mix of GET and POST

Tags: post, get, http-headers, firefox-addon

We can use Tamper Data for tampering the POST requests, but I want to know if there is any tool to tamper the requests which are mix of GET and POST
like : http://example.com/?time=123456&date=22-12-2012
and also have associated POST data.

With Tamper Data I can only change the POST parameters and not GET, and if I use another way to change GET parameters, I loses the POST data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). That gives you control over GET and POST data (the entire request in general) and should be able to do what you desire.

It even has its own associated [FiddlerScript](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/dev/) which helps automate handling (redirection, editing, etc) of web requests.

Comment: How can I use fiddler to pause the data, change it and then submit, just like Tamper Data ?

Comment: If you see the [second link](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/dev/) in my post, you can see that is possible. To 'fiddle' with outgoing/incoming requests.